# MySQL Time Based Trigger

Tags: mysql

I am coding a project and I need a time based trigger in MySQL. In this project there is a taking appointment module and 15 days are limit. When this 15 days finished, trigger must be triggered and insert new 15 days to the table. How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `event_scheduler` not `trigger`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: Triggers are triggered upon **action** and code that gets executed in time intervals are dealt by using event scheduler, since those are **events**. Like the guys before me commented correctly, you require the event scheduler that will execute a stored procedure or a sequence of inserts, it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I again have a problem. I'm trying to use this event code but mysql not accepts this code. Where is the error?
http://pastebin.com/cDmHgRzi

Comment: Click "edit" below your question and add the code **directly** into your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

- Use a delimiter as explained in [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)
- there must be no `S` at the end of `DAY` in `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 DAY` as explained in [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)
- The documentation says "As with stored routines, you can use compound-statement syntax in the DO clause by using the BEGIN and END keywords", so a `BEGIN` keyword must be added after the first `DO`
- [each statement must be separated with a semi-colon](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/entering-queries.html)
- [WHILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html) says the code must be enclosed between `WHILE search_condition DO` and `END WHILE`
- in your `INSERT`, `day` is a field: enclose it in backticks, not in quotes

**Fixed code**:

```
DELIMITER $$$
CREATE EVENT autoDayInsert ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 DAY DO BEGIN
    SET @dayCounter = 0;
    WHILE @dayCounter < 15 DO
        INSERT INTO appointmentDays(`day`) VALUES(NOW() + INTERVAL @dayCounter DAY);
        SET @dayCounter = @dayCounter +1;
    END WHILE;
END $$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I suggest you read the links I gave in my answer. In the future, refer to the official documentation when you have a problem: the information given there is accurate and up-to-date, and almost always comes with many examples that help understand the syntax to use.